# Unity Debug log not showing in iOS build

Tags: ios, debugging, logging, unity-game-engine

guys I've been struggling with the following issue for couple of days and hope that somebody could help me.

I want to get my app logs from running iOS device. If I run the app from the Xcode, then I see my logs in debug view as expected.

However, when I download a build from my testflight app I'm not able to access the logs anymore. Google suggest that I use Xcode -> Devices -> Log of a device, but there are only system events log and no messages from my app.

Running Unity 5.5.2.p2, Xcode 8.2.1. with ios 10 and 9 tested.

Would appreciate any help, because this issue is really exhausting.

Comment: Try in build setting choise Run in Xcode as Debug and check Development build. But i not sure.

Comment: already checked with no luck

Comment: Try create OnGUI method and GUI.Label.. It's simple code. You able use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LogCallback.html ...

Comment: Informational logs are not visible in debug builds, they will be stored in the output log file. Only higher severity level outputs are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more searching I found out that it's not possible, unfortunately. But I've managed to make a solution, hope it helps somebody.

Apple's native NSLog prints all the logs to a console app even after the app was downloaded from TestFlight.

I made a simple iOS plugin wich catches all the debug logs and forwards them to a NSLog. Make sure you call

```
LogManager.Init()
```

somewhere on app start.

Hope this will help somebody. The plugin is here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Yn93mXrM82ODZlbDVTNmo0QlU

Comment: Awesome! It was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

**Archiving for TestFlight means Build Configuration is release.**

SO you won't be able to see the dubug log on testflight build.

Follow this link to [make a debuggable TestFlight build](https://robertcastle.com/2012/10/make-debuggable-testflight-build/).

Or simply add `DEBUG=1` on `Release` section under `Preprocessor Macros`

[image]